# FOSS End-User reporting tool for XML files

Tags: gratis, open-source, cross-platform, reporting

We have recently begun receiving data in XML format from an existing business correspondent.  This format is not compatible with our existing software which is based upon 80 column unit records.  The new data is supplemental to rather than a replacement for the existing data transfer format and so there will be no effort expended on incorporating the new format into the existing software application.

However, some of our users would like to access this data and generate their own printed or pdf reports from it.  They are seeking the ability to select, format and analyse the contents using subtotals, page breaks, sorts and the like.

Is there a FOSS tool that runs on RH-EL6/7 Linux and on MS-Windows7+ platforms that gives end users this capability?